# In Hapi.js server is not starting

Tags: hapi.js

```
const Hapi=require('hapi');

//Init server
const server=new Hapi.Server();

//Add connection
server.connection({
    port:3000,
    host:'localhost'
});

//Home route

server.route({
    method:'GET',
    path:'/',
    handler:(request,reply)=>{
        reply('Hello World');
}
})



// Start Server
server.start((err) => {
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }

    console.log(`Server started at: ${server.info.uri}`);
});
```

> Blockquote
>   This is my first hapi.js server for printing hello world in home page but shows server.connection is not a function and also handlers are not promising.
>   Plz help me.

Comment: This code is not correct. See how you can start your Hapi.js server here: https://hapijs.com/tutorials/getting-started?lang=en_US

Comment: I have seen this code in youtube channel from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lprC0yYeFw           , which is a good and trusted channel

Comment: @ArmenAvetisyan does all the code is changed that's why it's not working.Is that so ??

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
const Hapi=require('hapi');
//Init server
const server = new Hapi.Server({ port: 3000, host: 'localhost' });
//Home route

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  handler: function (request, h) {
  return 'hello world';
    }
  });

// Start Server
server.start(err => {
    if (err) {
        // Fancy error handling here
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
    console.log(`Server started at ${ server.info.uri }`);
});
```

Hapi v17.0.0^ is not supporting for multiple connections for a single server and no longer passing the reply function as the second argument

Answer (score 1):

check you node.js  version older versions does not support the latest hapi format. there seems to be alot of diiference betwwen older versions and newer versions of hapi.js

```
const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi');

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const init = async () => {

const server = Hapi.server({
    port: port,
    host: 'localhost'
});

server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    handler: (request, h) => {
        return 'Hello World!';
    }
});

await server.start();
console.log('Server running on %s', server.info.uri);
};


init();
```